# How to archive the table data in SQL Server which has a unique key on a column

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with a unique key constraint on `name` column. Now I want to archive the data to an archive table. How can I ensure that no duplicate values will get inserted after archiving the data? Duplicate values in the sense the values included in the archive table.

Comment: Can you share what has been tried so far? Show us the table structure with all constraints for original and the archive table.

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways would be creating an [indexed view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/views/create-indexed-views) on both tables (assuming they are in the same database) and create a unique index on it:

```sql
create view dbo.MyView
with schemabinding
as

select t.Id, t.Name, ...
from dbo.MyTable t
union all
select t.Id, t.Name, ...
from dbo.MyTableArchve t;
go

create unique clustered index [UXC_MyView_Name] on dbo.MyView (Name);
go
```

There are many conditions an indexed view should satisfy, however; I recommend you to acquaint yourself with the documentation article linked above and decide whether it will work for you.